# How do I use the parameter 'bw=sj' in R

Tags: r, histogram

We have been told to make a histogram and line using our given data. I can make the histogram I think correctly. However we were told to use bw='sj' in our density function. I do not understand how I would put this to use.
i tried putting it in the hist() function as I thought it is a parameter however I get an error that says:

Warning messages:
1: In plot.window(xlim, ylim, "", ...) : "bw" is not a graphical parameter
2: In title(main = main, sub = sub, xlab = xlab, ylab = ylab, ...) :
"bw" is not a graphical parameter
3: In axis(1, ...) : "bw" is not a graphical parameter
4: In axis(2, ...) : "bw" is not a graphical parameter

This is part of my code that deals with the problem in R.

```
# histogram 1
rdi4p -> data_shhs[,'rdi4p']


hist(rdi4p  ,probability=TRUE,col=rgb(0,0,1,1/4),breaks=30,
         xlab="rdi4p",
         main="Histogram 1",col.axis="blue")

lines(x=density(x= rdi4p),type="l",col="blue",lwd=3)
```

Answer (score 2):

Of course, I don't have your data to work on (in particular we would need to know what `rdi4p` and `sj` were to make this fully reproducible), so I'll make up our own values for these variables:

```r
set.seed(1)                     # Make example reproducible
rdi4p <- rnorm(1000)            # Vector of 1000 samples from normal distribution
sj    <- diff(range(rdi4p))/30  # 1/30 of the range of vector rdi4p
```

Now we draw the histogram using your code:

```r
hist(rdi4p, probability = TRUE, col = rgb(0, 0, 1, 1/4), breaks = 30,
     xlab = "rdi4p", main = "Histogram 1", col.axis = "blue")
```

[image]

and then we add the line. Note that we have to pass the parameter `bw = sj` to the `density` function, which is itself sitting inside the call to `lines`:

```r
lines(x = density(x = rdi4p, bw = sj), type = "l", col = "blue", lwd = 3)
```

[image]

Comment: I seee, I was confused on how to use it but I understand now. Thankyou